# Check the value of textbox which is hide/shown accordingly using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc3 application. In my razor view I set the textbox like this :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model[i].FieldValue, new { @class = "yesNoNotApplicableTextbox", style = "display: none;" })
```

Initially it's hidden. There is condition that must be hit to show it. And I show it like this :

```
$('.YesNoNotApplicable').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === '2') {
        $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').hide();
    }
});
```

In few words `.YesNoNotApplicable` is class for a dropdown and if certain value is selected then I show the textbox.

All this part of a form, and on submit I want to check the value of the textbox (I haven't think yet of how to check if it's shown or hidden I wanted to implement the check first) so I do this :

```
 $(".yesNoNotApplicableTextbox input[type='text']").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().trim().length < 1) {
                $(this).focus();
                throw "Please insert text!";
            }
        });
```

But no matter if I select the correct value from the dropdown which makes the textbox visible or not the check is not performed. The textbox is empty but I don't get the error.

Here is the generated HTML for this textbox when it's hidden :

```
<input class="yesNoNotApplicableTextbox" type="text" value="" style="display: none;" name="[14].FieldValue">
```

and then when I show it :

```
<input class="yesNoNotApplicableTextbox" type="text" value="" style="" name="[14].FieldValue">
```

How can I perform the value check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox` is the input, so when you do this :

```
$(".yesNoNotApplicableTextbox input[type='text']")
```

You select the children input of `.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox`. Try this :

```
$("input.yesNoNotApplicableTextbox[type='text']")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I thought that the display style is causing this problem. You saved me lots of time.